# Unique identifier for Racket objects?

Tags: racket

Is there a way to get a unique identifier for an object in Racket? For instance, when we use Racket's `eq?` operator to check whether two variables refer to the *same* object, what identifier is it using to achieve this comparison?

I'm looking for something like python's [`id` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) or Ruby's [`object_id` method](https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/object_id), in other words, some function `id` such that `(= (id obj) (id obj2))` means that `(eq? obj obj2)` is true.

Some relevant docs:

[Object Identity and Comparisons](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/eval-model.html?q=eq%3F#%28part._model-eq%29)

[Variables and Locations](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/eval-model.html?q=eq%3F#%28part._vars-and-locs%29)

Comment: What do you need such an number for?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't recall exactly now, but it had something to do with understanding how the Racket interpreter works in some context, or maybe it was related to "prefab" struct types. In any case, I believe it was related to learning. If I remember what it was or think of another worthy use case, I'll plan to follow up with a comment here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is [`eq-hash-code`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/hashtables.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._eq-hash-code%29%29) what you want?

```
> (define l1 '(1))
> (define l2 '(1))
> (eq? l1 l2)
#f
> (eq-hash-code l1)
9408
> (eq-hash-code l2)
9412
```

Answer (score 3):

There's a way to get a C pointer of an object via `ffi/unsafe`, with the obvious caveat that it's UNSAFE.

```
;; from https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Address_of_a_variable#Racket

(require ffi/unsafe)

(define (madness v) ; i'm so sorry
   (cast v _racket _gcpointer))
```

To use it:

```
(define a (list 1 2))
(define b (list 1 2))

(printf "a and b have different address: ~a ~a\n"
        (equal? (madness a) (madness b))
        (eq? a b))

(printf "a and a have the same address: ~a ~a\n"
        (equal? (madness a) (madness a))
        (eq? a a))

(printf "1 and 1 have the same address: ~a ~a\n"
        (equal? (madness 1) (madness 1))
        (eq? 1 1))
```

Though the pointer is not a number or an identifier. It's an opaque object... So in a sense, this is kinda useless. You could have used the real objects with `eq?` instead.

I also don't know any guarantee of this method. In particular, I don't know if the pointer will be updated to its latest value when the copy GC copies objects.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an implementation of such a function using a weak hash table.
Using a weak hash table ensures that objects are garbage collected correctly
even if we have given it an id.

```
#lang racket

(define ht (make-weak-hasheq))
(define next 0)

(define (get-id x)
  (define id (hash-ref ht x #f))
  (or id
      (begin0
        next
        (hash-set! ht x next)
        (set! next (+ next 1)))))

(get-id 'a)
(get-id 'b)
(get-id 'a)
```

Note that Sylwester's advice is sound. The standard is to store the value directly.

Answer (score 2):

You most likely won't find an identity, but the object itself is only `eq?` with itself and nothing else. `eq?` basically compares the address location of the values. So if you want an id you can just store the whole object at that place and it will be unique.

A location is a binding. Think of it as an address you cannot get and an address which has an address to a object. Eg. a binding `((lambda (a) a) 10)` would store the address location of the object `10` in the first stack address and the code in the body just returns that same address. A location can change by `set!` but you'll never get the memory location of it.

It's common for lisp systems to store values in pointers. That means that some types and values doesn't really have an object at the address, but the address has a value and type encoded in it that the system knows. Typically small integers, chars, symbols and booleans can be pointer equal even though they are constructed at different times. eg. `'(1 2 3)` would only use 3 pairs and not any space for the values 1-3 and `()`.